# Apache Spark DataFrame no RDD partitioning

Tags: java, parallel-processing, apache-spark

According to new Spark Docs, using Spark's `DataFrame` `should be preferred over using JdbcRDD`.

First touch was pretty enjoyable until I faced first problem - `DataFrame` has no `flatMapToPair()` method. The first mind was to convert it into `JavaRDD` and I did it.

Everything was fine, I wrote my code using this approach and that noticed that such code:

```
JavaRDD<Row> myRDD = dataFrame.toJavaRDD();
int amount = myRDD.partitions().length
```

produces `1`. All code below such transformation to `JavaRDD` is absolutely inefficient. Force repartitioning of RDD takes a good piece of time and makes bigger overhead than code, that works with 1 partition.

How to deal with it?

While using `JdbcRDD` we wrote specific SQL with "pager" like `WHERE id >= ? and id <= ?` that was used to create partitions. How to make something like this using `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`

```
 val connectionString` = "jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@111.11.1.11:1521:ORDERS"                                          
 val ordersDF = sqlContext.load("jdbc", 
                       Map( "url" -> connectionString,
                            "dbtable" -> "(select *  from CUSTOMER_ORDERS)",
                            "partitionColumn" -> "ORDER_ID",
                            "lowerBound"-> "1000",
                            "upperBound" -> "40000",
                            "numPartitions"-> "10"))
```